# Explicit solution of Initial Value Problem for inviscid Burgers equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I've been working on solving PDEs with conditions recently and have come across this question:

> Obtain the explicit solution $u(x,t)$ to the IVP:
>   $$u_t+uu_x=2t,   \quad -\infty < x <\infty, \quad t>0,$$
>   $$u(x,0)=x, \quad -\infty<x<\infty.$$
>   Casting your answer as a function of $x$ and $t$ only.

I have had issues getting a solution in just terms of $x$ and $t$, and have been worried that I am misunderstanding how to tackle this. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Did you try separation of variables?

Comment: Hmm, I havent yet. Ill take a look

Comment: The problem you have is just the inviscid Burgers equation. Separation of variables probably won't work as the PDE is nonlinear. Use the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). You can find plenty of examples on the MSE site to guide you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by user Mattos is right. The [method of characteristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) for the quasi-linear case boils down to 2 coupled initial value ODEs

$$ \frac{du}{dt}~=~2t, \qquad u(t\!=\!0)~=~x_0,\tag{1a} $$

$$ \frac{dx}{dt}~=~u, \qquad x(t\!=\!0)~=~x_0, \tag{1b}$$

with solutions

$$ u~=~x_0+t^2,\tag{2a}$$

$$ x~=~(1+t)x_0 +\frac{t^3}{3}. \tag{2b}$$

Now eliminate $x_0$ from eq. (2a) by use of eq. (2b):

$$ u(x,t)~=~\frac{x-\frac{t^3}{3}}{1+t} +t^2. \tag{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering, I was setting up my solution incorrectly and it got off track. Thank you for clearing this up!